# Can't figure out source of interference reading 10k POTs with 74HC4051

Tags: analog

I realize this gets asked a lot, but I feel like I've applied the most common fixes without success. I have 10 10k potentiometers plugged in to an arduino via a custom shield. 2 are wired directly to the MC via A2 and A3. The other 8 are plugged in via a 74HC4051 multiplexer. The 2 plugged in directly work great. The other 8 show a ton of cross talk and don't seem to vary as much as they should. Here is some example output on the arduino serial plotter:

[image]

Things I have tried:

1. I put a delay between the pin selection and the read.
2. I'm reading twice (with a delay in between) and discarding the first read.

I'd use an MCP2308 if I were doing this again, but in the mean time is there anything else I can try?

Here is my schematic:

[image]

Each pot is plugged in to 5V and ground, with the wiper wired directly to the pin, all via jumper cables to the shield. Here's a picture of how this works (apologies for the mess):

[image: Board Picture]

The pin blocks have, per row, one pin each feeding in to a multiplexer input, and another attached to the GND and +5V planes on the PCB. These are attached to +5V and GND on the arduino:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
const int selectPins[3] = {8, 12, 13}; // S0, S1, S2
const int zInput = A1; // Connect common (Z) to A1 (analog input)
const int DIMp = A2;
const int bDIMp = A3;
void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(9600); // Initialize the serial port
  // Set up the select pins as outputs:
  for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
  {
    pinMode(selectPins[i], OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(selectPins[i], HIGH);
  }
  pinMode(zInput, INPUT);
  pinMode(DIMp, INPUT);
  pinMode(bDIMp, INPUT);
}

// The selectMuxPin function sets the S0, S1, and S2 pins
// accordingly, given a pin from 0-7.
void selectAMuxPin(byte pin)
{
  for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
  {
    if (pin & (1<<i))
      digitalWrite(selectPins[i], HIGH);
    else
      digitalWrite(selectPins[i], LOW);
  }
}

void loop() 
{
  // Loop through the hard wired dimmers
  Serial.print(String(analogRead(DIMp))+" ");
  Serial.print(String(analogRead(bDIMp))+" ");
  // Loop through all eight pins.
  for (byte pin=0; pin<=7; pin++)
  {
    selectAMuxPin(pin); // Select one at a time
    delayMicroseconds(500); // delay after pin select
    int inputValueb = analogRead(zInput); // read Z
    delayMicroseconds(150); //delay after first read
    inputValueb = analogRead(zInput); // read Z again
    Serial.print(String(inputValueb) + " ");
  }
  Serial.println();
}
```

Comment: "Z1" is connected to A0 but you are reading from A1?

Comment: it is difficult to guess the `anything else I can try` because you did not say what you already tried

Comment: Sorry - the Z1 is a mistake because I removed some code related to the second chip. I tried adding a delay between reads, and I tried reading twice and throwing out the first read.

Comment: Please [edit] your question, informations in the comments are very hard to find.

Comment: I'd start with decoupling capacitor for 4051. Next step would be reading 0V channel before reading analog input channel (but that's not possible by analogRead), to remove charge of sampling capacitor.

Comment: Where does the 5V used on Poties come from? Is it the same voltage you use as the reference voltage for the Arduino ADCs?  Do the Arduino and the poties have the same GND? It would be easier to find someting, if we could see a picture of your setup. Schematics say nothing about what you have really done. ;-)

Comment: Thanks everyone for your helpful comments. I've edited the post with cleaned up code and added my (no doubt shameful) PCB layout and a picture of the actual setup.

@PeterPaulKiefer : The poties are plugged in to the arduino Gnd and +5V pins via copper fills on the PCB - I'm guessing that's not the way to go?

Comment: Have you tried to connect only one poti to the muxer? Setting the other 1st over a resistor to GND (Just for safety, if there is a short circuit) and 2nd leave them open. I think the program works fine. But there seems to be a problem with the wiring of the poties or PCB. There is an influence of the potis on each other and/or on the ref voltage. And the graph show also a voltage offset. That's a hint that the feeding voltage of the poties and the reference do not match.

Comment: Have you a multimeter to measure the voltages before the muxer. Perhaps that gives you a hint.

Comment: And one thing, but it might be nonsense: I saw in the layout that the chips are oriented in different ways.  But on the picture it seems as if they are inserted in the same way. If they use different marker to indicate pin 1.

Comment: They are pointing in different directions! Too bad - that would have been an easy fix. I'll compare the ref voltage when I can get back to the shop. Per @KIIV I'll also try putting a .1 uf capacitor between the IC VCC and gnd. Not sure how to read 0V.

Comment: There is an internal ADC channel connected directly to the ground. But as i wrote, it's not reachable by analogRead. So unless you have free analog input that can be grounded, you'll have to try to read it directly by setting ADC registers. (that's for elliminating crosstalk caused by too big input impedance that can't charge/discharge sampling capacitor enough - causing crosstalk with previous reading)